# MSVCR80.dll runtime errors when using lua with luafilesystem

Tags: windows, lua, runtime-error, yaml, msvcrt

Following on from a previous question (which was answered) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39000722/issues-installing-yaml-for-lua-with-luarocks-during-the-c-compile/39015671?noredirect=1#comment65388960_39015671). I managed to resolve the particular issue, but then hit another one - there are details in the 3rd update of that question but I am moving them here since it is now a new question:

I have installed luarocks (which comes with lua and a version of msvcr80.dll). Then I finally managed to get yaml installed. I could not install it directly from the "luarocks install yaml" command line because of local IT blocks, but I Was able to download the src.rock files and install it as follows (with its dependencies):

```
luarocks install luafilesystem-1.6.3-2.src.rock    (required buy lub)
luarocks install lub-1.1.0-1.src.rock              (required by yaml)
luarocks install yaml-1.1.2-1.src.rock CC="gcc -DYAML_DECLARE_STATIC"
```

Then I added the package paths into my script (for now) so that I can use yaml, here is my very basic test script:

```
package.path = "D:\\user\\install\\lua\\luarocks\\systree\\share\\lua\\5.1\\?\\init.lua;" .. package.path
print("package.path: " .. package.path)
local yaml = require("yaml")
local data = yaml.load("mytest.yaml")
```

As you can see all I am doing in including yaml and trying to read in a yaml file - very basic. When I run it I get the following error:

[image]

And my log looks like:

```
D:\user\install\lua\luarocks\systree\share\lua\5.1\?\init.lua;D:\user\install\lua\luarocks\systree\share\lua\5.1\?.lua;D:\user\install\lua\luarocks\systree\share\lua\5.1\?\init.lua;./?.lua;./?/init.lua;./lua/?.lua;./lua/?/init.lua;D:\user\install\lua\zerobrane\lualibs/?/?.lua;D:\user\install\lua\zerobrane\lualibs/?.lua;D:\user\install\lua\zerobrane\lualibs/?/?/init.lua;D:\user\install\lua\zerobrane\lualibs/?/init.lua
D:\user\install\lua\zerobrane\bin\lua.exe: error loading module 'lfs' from file 'D:\user\install\lua\luarocks\systree\lib\lua\5.1\lfs.dll':
    The specified procedure could not be found.


stack traceback:
    [C]: at 0x66df0460
    [C]: in function 'require'
    ...\install\lua\luarocks\systree\share\lua\5.1\lub\init.lua:17: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'require'
    ...install\lua\luarocks\systree\share\lua\5.1\yaml\init.lua:25: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'require'
    D:\user\workspace\_lua\myluatest.lua:3: in main chunk
    [C]: at 0x00402a57
Program completed in 56.64 seconds (pid: 15856).
```

It is definitely using the MSVCR80.DLL within the luarocks install folder because when I change the name of that file it complains that the DLL is missing.

So the issue appears to be that luafilesystem must need a different version of MSVCR80.DLL then luarocks has installed. I have no idea how to resolve that. If I was able to run the command "luarocks install yaml" would that make any difference? - is there some update for the file msvcr80.dll? but if I change this file version then won't other parts of luarocks stop working? - I really don't get it.

Only one idea comes to mind and that would be to install 'lfs' and link it against the luarocks version of MSVCR80.DLL, but again - I don't know how to do that.

**UPDATE**

Ok, I found this article that looks promising: [link-to-article](https://github.com/keplerproject/luafilesystem/issues/25). But somewhere along the lines I no longer get the same error. Now the error I get is:

[image]

And the log says:

```
d:\user\install\lua\zerobrane\bin\lua.exe: error loading module 'lfs' from file 'D:\user\install\lua\luarocks\systree\lib\lua\5.1\lfs.dll':
    A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.


stack traceback:
    [C]: at 0x66df0460
    [C]: in function 'require'
    ...\install\lua\luarocks\systree\share\lua\5.1\lub\init.lua:17: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'require'
    ...install\lua\luarocks\systree\share\lua\5.1\yaml\init.lua:25: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'require'
    D:\user\workspace\_lua\myluatest.lua:10: in main chunk
    [C]: at 0x00402a57
Program completed in 56.52 seconds (pid: 15220).
```

I have tried removing lua/love/luarocks + all packages and started all over again. As soon as I try to install luafilesystem (weather I link to MSVCR80.dll or not) I get this same error.

I am currently in microsoft runtime hell :o .. please help!

**UPDATE2**

So I removed everything lua -related (paths and all). Then I re-installed:

- luarocks
- luasockets
- lfs
- lub
- yaml
- zerobrain

I had to add luarocks to my path so that I could run lua.exe.

I then ran my test script. It failed with the error `...procedure entry point utime could not be located...`.

So back to normal. Then I got the lfs source from git. I ran the make (which links using `-lMSVCR80`. I re-ran the link command without MSVCR80 to produce a new lfs.dll and copied it over the one in `D:\user\install\lua\luarocks\systree\lib\lua\5.1`.

Now I ran my script again to give me the result it complained that it could not find `lub\autoload.lua`. I ran the following script just to see if lfs is ok:

```
package.path = "D:\\adadachanji\\install\\lua\\luarocks\\systree\\share\\lua\\5.1\\?\\init.lua;" .. package.path
package.path = "D:\\adadachanji\\install\\lua\\luarocks\\systree\\share\\lua\\5.1\\?.lua;" .. package.path
print("package.path: " .. package.path)

local lfs = require( "lfs" )
local doc_path = "d:\\user"
print("doc_path = " .. doc_path)
for file in lfs.dir( doc_path ) do

    print( "Found file: " .. file )
end
```

And this worked ok :)

Now I add lub: `local lub = require("lub")`, run again: it works :)

Now I add yaml: `local yaml = require("yaml")`, then I get my error.

I am running this in zerobrain IDE. I then decide to try this on the command line (because I think zerobrain has its own lua versions).

... and it works!

So I have found a whole pile of issues here... zerobrains (literally) appears to be a steaming pile of %$ - ignores completely whatever you install elsewhere. There are bugs in yaml that require extra command line parameters. There is a 64-bit issue in lfs. None of these things are really integrated in any sensible way...

I will post an answer detailing the steps required to put the following together:

- lua (via luarocks)
- lua socket
- love
- yaml (using lfs and lub)

Not a long list - and should be simple, but is not.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my installation notes as promised... I have not detailed where I got all the files from exactly, but a quick google search should get you there. If not ask and I will find them!

## 1. Install LuaRocks with LUA 5.1 and LOVE

1. Donwload LuaRocks and then enter the following command (modify path as required): install /L /p D:\install-path\luarocks /MW /F

   **Note:** /L tells this to install Lua 5.1 for you (so you don't also have to install this) and it uses mingw compiler which needs to be in your path.

   **Note:** You can install mingw online "mingw-get-setup.exe" - its default path is: C:\MinGW, but put it whereever you want!
2. Download "love-0.10.1-win64" (or whatever version) and unzip it to whereever you want it to live (it does not need installing)
3. Add/modify the following env vars (modify path as required):

   - PATH     : `D:\install-path\luarocks;D:\install-path\love;`
   - PATHEXT  : `.LUA`
   - LUA_PATH : `D:\install-path\luarocks\systree\share\lua\5.1\?.lua;D:\install-path\luarocks\systree\share\lua\5.1\?\init.lua;`
   - LUA_CPATH:   `D:\install-path\luarocks\systree\lib\lua\5.1\?.dll`

## 2. Install LUA Socket

1. Download `luasocket-2.0.2-3.win32-x86.rock` and open a cmd prompt as admin
2. cd into the download folder
3. run the command: `luarocks install luasocket-2.0.2-3.win32-x86.rock`
4. Add the following environmental variables (modify path as required):

   - `LUA_PATH=D:\install-path\luarocks\systree\share\lua\5.1\?.lua`
   - `LUA_CPATH=D:\install-path\luarocks\systree\lib\lua\5.1\?.dll`

## 3. LUA File System (LFS)

There is an issue for 64-bit systems where function names are changed to from function() to function32() (well done microsoft) such that older libraries using newer MSVCR dlls have an issue where they can't find the function start point. These instructions show how to install lfs (which has this issue) and get around it. If you are using 32-bit you might not have to do this -

1. Get luafilesystem from the git repo, extract and cd into that folder (luafilesystem-master).
2. Run `luarocks make` this will install lfs (note that the linker line uses -lMSVCR80 at the end - this is printed in the stdout).
3. Copy and paste the linker line and remove the "-lMSVCR80" and press enter. This will make a new new local lfs.dll
4. Copy this over the top of the existing lfs.dll here: `D:\install-path\luarocks\systree\lib\lua\5.1`

## 4. YAML \ LUB

1. In your mingw bin folder make sure that mingw32-gcc.exe exists, if it does not then copy gcc.exe to mingw32-gcc.exe.
2. Open a command promt as admin and cd to your download folder
3. For each of the following, download the src.rock file from https://luarocks.org and Run the following commands (yaml has dependency on lub, lub has dependency on luafilesystem):

   - (deprecated - see section 3 instead): `luarocks install luafilesystem-1.6.3-2.src.rock`
   - `luarocks install lub-1.1.0-1.src.rock`
   - `luarocks install yaml-1.1.2-1.src.rock CC="mingw32-gcc -DYAML_DECLARE_STATIC"`

## 5. Other Pitfalls

1. Don't bother with brainless (zerobrane) - unless you want to use the version of lua that it comes with which causes a conflict with your nice luarocks setup. Plus it can't see to handle any depth of code completion (i.e. any add on module). If you want to use it with love, you need to set the active folder to the sub folder where your main.lua file is.... and then its file tree view zooms into this folder so you can't easily switch back to other folders.
2. Don't use consoleZ (or console 2 as it may also be known). It seems to have issues with the environmental variables. If I add the var LUA_PATH I get strange errors, in fact if I add any var starting with "LUA..." I get errors - I already have other vars that start with "LUA" so maybe it can handle only so many before it gives up! Anyway, using bog-standard command prompt worked, so I ditched consoleZ and started using ConEmu - much better!

---

I think that is about it... honestly - it feels like this stuff hangs together by old bits of blue-tack and a sprinkling of luck :o - this is my first lua/love experience and its been a pretty crappy one so far; but now I can actually do some work lets see if it is as good as its reputation... :)
Please feel free to add / comment on extra pitfalls/notes and I will update (or update it yourself).